# 1st order linear differential equation, integral help

Tags: integration, derivatives

I need to solve this problem:

$y+ y\cos(x) = \sin(x)+\cos(x)$

General form :

$y' + f(x)y = g(x)$

so, the solution will be

$y(x) = e^{-\int_{}{} f(x)dx} \cdot \left( \int_{}{} e^{\int_{}{} f(x)dx} \cdot g(x)dx + C\right) $

so my

$f(x) = \cos(x) \\
g(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$

and I'm having trouble with an integral that I get

$\int_{}{}e^{\sin(x)}(\sin(x) + \cos(x)) dx + C$

more specific this integral:

$\int_{}{}e^{\sin(x)}\sin(x)dx$

**Thanks**

Edit: add photo

[Linear differential equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xW2c.png)

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\color{red}{y'}+ y\cos(x) = \sin(x)+\cos(x)$?

Comment: It seems that this differential equation does not have a nice [closed form solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%2B+y+cos%28x%29+%3D+sin%28x%29+%2B+cos%28x%29). With that in mind, it would be helpful if you could give us some context. Is this equation from some kind of assignment? Do you have a reason to believe that the solution will be "nice" in some way (e.g. expressible in closed form)?

Comment: Also, you should check to make sure that you copied the question correctly if it is from an assignment

Comment: Hi, it just says "Solve linear differential equations". I add photo in the post so there shouldn't be any type-mistakes.
Thanks